# Why can non-capturing lambdas not be default-constructed, and is it possible to work around this?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

It is possible to use the type of a lambda as a template argument, like

```
template<typename InArg, typename Function>
class selfCompose {
  Function f;
 public:
  selfCompose(Function f): f(f) {}
  auto operator() (InArg x) -> decltype(f(f(x))) {
    return f(f(x));                              }
};

int main() {
  auto f = [](int x){return x*x;};
  std::cout << selfCompose<int, decltype(f)>(f)(4)  //  yields (4²)² = 256
            << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

However, this double use of `f` is kind of redundant. We can omit passing the lambda's *type* as the template (casting it to a suitable `std::function` (at loss of polymorphism – but C++ lambdas aren't parametrically polymorphic anyway)), however I have an application where I'd much prefer not having to pass its *value* to the constructor (because I'd like to use my class's initialisations themselves as a template parameter, where a particular constructor signature is expected). I'd like it to work like

```
template<class InArg, class Function>
class selfCompose {
  Function f;
 public:
  selfCompose() {}  // default constructor for f
  auto operator() (InArg x) -> decltype(f(f(x))) {
    return f(f(x));                              }
};

int main() {
  auto f = [](int x){return x*x;};
  std::cout << selfCompose<int, decltype(f)>()(4) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

but this doesn't compile because lambdas have a deleted default constructor. Which is of course inevitable for *capturing* lambdas, but for simple ones like the one in my example this doesn't make much sense to me: they don't need to reference any local variables.

Is there some other way to get this functionality, or do I have to resort to defining the lambda old-fashionly as a named class?

```
struct myFun {
  auto operator() (int x) -> int {return x*x;}
};
```

(of course, the lambda functions I'd like to use aren't *quite* as simple as `x → x²`, so just selecting from a few standard function classes wouldn't be flexible enough)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Benjamin already posted a nice workaround for your case. You could use that.

My solution is just an improved version of Benjamin's answer where you don't have to specify the lambda parameter *type*. So instead of writing this:

```
make_selfCompose<int>(f)(4); //Benjamin's solution
```

you can write just this:

```
make_selfCompose(f)(4); //improved - absence `int` template argument.
```

and let `make_selfCompose` deduce the lambda parameter type itself.

For this solution, lets write first `function_traits` class template as:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
struct function_traits : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct function_traits<R(C::*)(A...) const>
{
   template <size_t i>
   struct arg
   {
      typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<A...>>::type type;
   };
};
```

Then here is an improved version of `make_selfCompose`:

```
template<typename Fun> //<--- now it has one template parameter
selfCompose<typename function_traits<Fun>::template arg<0>::type, Fun>
make_selfCompose(Fun f)
{
  typedef typename function_traits<Fun>::template arg<0>::type InArg; //deduce it
  return selfCompose<InArg, decltype(f)>(f);
}
```

Here is test program:

```
int main() {
  auto f = [](int x){return x*x;};
  std::cout << make_selfCompose(f)(4)  //notice the relief here!
            << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

See [an online demo](http://ideone.com/1sNy9Z)

Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but +1 for the `function_traits` stuff (though I'm afraid it doesn't help much in my problem – but it looks very interesting, I need to learn this) and accepted for explaining why it doesn't work as I'd like.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: You could improve `function_traits` class template, and use it generically to make your code work.

Comment: To be fair, it wouldn't be hard for the standard to require that stateless lambdas can be trivially constructed, while still being convertible to pointer-to-function.  Then `[](){}->void` would be `struct Stateless { static void doop() {}; void operator()() const {doop();}; operator void(*)()() const { return &Stateless::doop; }; };` or the standardese equivalent.  As far as I can tell, this would be consistent with almost all standards-compliant C++11 code (except for ones that somehow detect deleted constructors).

Comment: @Yakk: But the fact is that the Standard doesn't require that. I'm not saying that that is not possible, just that it is not Standard C++ requirement.

Comment: *nod*, and in fact it requires the opposite.  It does mean that there is "no good reason" for the Standard to have required the opposite (that a stateless lambda must be unconstructable).  Admittedly, the `std::map<Key, Value, decltype( [](Key const& left, Key const& right) { return left.foo < right.foo; }) >` looks pretty hacky, so that might be a reason to say "no, no default ctor for j00".

Comment: "The type of lambda is not necessarily a class." -- Wrong, it's required to be a unique, unnamed non-union class type (`§5.1.2/3`). It's also required to overload `operator()` (same clause, p5).

Comment: @Yakk: That is already dealt with thanks to lambdas not being allowed in an unevaluated context (like `decltype`).

Comment: "In fact, the Standard requires stateless lambda to be convertible to pointer-to-function. So stateless lambdas are functionally free functions, not class." Total non sequitur. I don't see how the conclusion possibly follows. As Xeo point out, the reality is exactly the opposite: it *must* be a class type.

Comment: Would you prefer that? Apperently the bits about uniqueness are indeed wrong, however it's still the answer that best adresses my problem. (Though I decided to completely refactor the use case now.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Alright. I removed the incorrect part from my answer.

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks for the info. I removed the incorrect part from my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can follow the example of functions like `make_pair` and `make_shared`:

```
template<typename InArg, typename Function>
selfCompose<InArg, Function> make_selfCompose(Function f)
{
  return selfCompose<InArg, decltype(f)>(f);
}

int main() {
  auto f = [](int x){return x*x;};
  std::cout << make_selfCompose<int>(f)(4)
            << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's nice, but it's just a wrapper for the way I do _not_ want to go right now: pass `f` as a value. What I'd like to do is to pass _only the type_ of `f`: since this type has only one value at all (namely `f`) it should be possible to deduce it in the default contructor.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: type of `f` is just type. It can have many values. Think of `max()` and `min()` for example, they're different, but both could have same type `int(int,int)`. So if you're given `int(int,int)`, then you cannot know which function it is.

Comment: @Nawaz not really. The obvious implementation of my lambda is just a stateless class with one member, `operator()`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: It is not necessarily a class. In fact, the Standard requires *stateless* lambda to be convertible to pointer-to-function. So stateless lambdas are free functions, not class.

Comment: @Nawaz lots of things are convertible in C++, e.g. `int -> double`, yet these are quite different types. The type of a lambda is certainly not _equal_ to the type of the function pointer it can be converted to.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: "certainly"? Also, member-function-pointers are NOT convertible to pointer-to-function. Also, the standard doesn't require lambda to be class!

Comment: @Nawaz could you write your considerations as an answer? I think I get the point.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Alright. Let me write an answer with an improved version of Benjamin solution.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: The fact that all instances are equal does not mean that there is a unique instance. Consider `struct X {}; X a,b,c;` All instances of `X` are *equivalent* (have the same behavior) but are not the same (have different identities). I don't quite understand why you don't want to pass the lambda as an argument, in particular what is so different between `compose<decltype(f)>(5)` and `compose(f)(5)` (I actually find the second more pleasant to read). If you are concerned about possible optimizations, don't, the compiler knows what to do.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Exactly: they're equivalent, and that would be completely fine in my application. — I'm not concerned about performance, it's just that I'd like to pass a type comparable to `selfCompose<int, decltype(f)>` as a template parameter to an existing class which will itself instantiate multiple different instances of the parameter class, and is not prepared to pass any extra arguments to the constructors.

Answer (score 1):

If `selfCompose` is made polymorphic, there is no need to either explicitly pass the parameter type or to inspect the stored functor type. The latter means that it will also be able to deal with polymorphic functors.

```
template<typename Functor>
struct self_compose_type {
    // Omitting encapsulation for brevity
    Functor functor;

    // It is possible to overload operator() to deal
    // with all cv and ref qualifiers combinations
    template<typename... T>
    auto operator()(T&&... t)
    // Don't use std::result_of for the return type
    -> decltype( std::declval<Functor&>()(std::declval<T>()...) )
    { return functor(std::forward<T>(t)...); }
};

template<typename Functor>
self_compose_type<Functor>
self_compose(Functor&& functor)
{ return { std::forward<Functor>(functor) }; }

// C++03 style:
template<typename Functor>
self_compose_type<typename std::decay<Functor>::type>
make_self_compose(Functor&& functor)
{ return { std::forward<Functor>(functor) }; }
```

It is not necessary to make the `operator()` variadic, you can make it accept exactly one argument if you so wish.